# Resources for API Hooking and DLL Injection

Tags: dll-injection, function-hooking

What are great resources and essential skills needed to become a proficient reverse engineer regarding API Hooking and DLL Injection? I would like to use a comprehensive book instead of scattered white-papers across the web.

Comment: See here: http://jbremer.org/x86-api-hooking-demystified/